# Is high availability required for nascent applications with low budget, if data loss is a concern?

Tags: mysql, neo4j, cluster-computing, high-availability, galera

I am rolling out my app in the next couple months, which is basically a variant of a social network but with a purpose. Now I have not included any high availability factor or any form of clustering or replication. Initially I thought I would start with one server since i would have minimal requests and later expand to a cluster based on the traffic and requests.

But while load testing I saw my database crash due space issues and I spend some time recovering it. So to make my app a going concern I don't want to lose my database or any data for that matter if my database crashes, goes corrupt or for any other reasons.

I am using both MySQL and Neo4j together and my application tries to keep them in sync. I feel tempted to implement a MySQL and Neo4j cluster using Galera MySQL cluster and Neo4j HA cluster respectively over three Amazon instances. It seems to be an overkill though considering I won't have enough traffic in the beginning and most of my resource would be idle (and expensive).

I am ready to put in the extra effort but money-wise I want to be wise! Please let me know if in the initial stage I should go for HA or take a risk and be satisfied with backups and be content with data loss if any due to failures.

Comment: What level of usage are you expecting in the first month of live e.g. how many users a day? One of the things to learn is that you might try scaling to 100K users a day and only find you get 10 a day. Thus, it's important not to scale until you know it is coming - spend the time on features instead?

Comment: You could always run a cron task to keep an eye on disk space, and put the app into read-only mode if space gets too low. In the longer term you should have notification monitors for this.

Comment: @halfer Thanks for the response! Yes i am not expecting more than 10-100 users a day for the first 6 months. I expect at least a year before the traffic ramps up and i am targeting total 50,000 users to be optimistic for the initial year. But do i run the risk of losing the existing data within the first year or getting a bad name due to loss of certain data for any reason.

Comment: A basic VPS can do 50K users per day if your app is reasonably well-tuned - that allows for 1 page every 1.7 seconds. Of course they will not be evenly distributed throughout the day, but it's still not a major load. 50K users a day is optimistic though - you need to see if people will use it first!

Comment: @halfer Thanks again. So if i don't have enough load on the server the risk for database crash or corruption should be negligible right? Which means i should be ok with daily or weekly backups.

Comment: I would say so. However if you wish, you could set up another VPS with another MySQL instance, and set it to [replicate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html) continuously. I don't know Amazon services, but it sounds like you could do this with a couple of ordinary VPS servers, each having 1G RAM to start with? Of course, keep your daily/weekly backups too.

Answer (score 3):

High availability is one piece of a reliable infrastructure but I'd put it much lower on my priorities list than investment in automated backup, deployment, and monitoring. For me, the key part of your experience and question is, "I saw my database crash due space issues and I spend some time recovering it." This happened in testing, so I wouldn't expect you to have everything sailing along, but in an ideally configured production environment, you'd know about your space issues ahead of time and address them on your terms. If it did go down, you wouldn't recover, you'd **restore**, and this would be more of an inconvenience than anything else.

Since you're worried about uptime and not performance, all you really need to focus on now is the uptime expectation of your app. If you only have one server and monitoring informs you of an error that will require brief downtime -- maybe you need to upgrade hardware, move to new storage, install a critical patch -- is it acceptable to be offline for a brief period of time?

If so, skip HA for now and make sure you have all the proactive layers in place. Maybe invest some money that would go towards servers in an HA environment on consultants to make your environment rock solid if there's any concern that you're missing something.

If not, I think you have your answer!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would definitely expect my app to be up all the time or else it will drive away the users that i would have started with. And based on your answer it seems i may experience some brief downtime due to various reasons like an error that requires downtime, upgrading hardware, storage, patching up etc. I think most  startups with limited budgets would take this risk of not going with HA and would rather focus on other improvement activities as you have mentioned above. In the end it seems its all a trade off between resources available and priorities.

Comment: Everything is a tradeoff between resources and priorities! In a low-traffic environment, though, HA ends up being a very expensive solution to a problem you can almost entirely avoid with the right precautions. If you're not relying on it for load-balancing, all that hardware is just sitting around, adding complexity and cost.